# API for creating groups and adding friends to it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any API using which my application can create a new groups and also add friends to that group. and should be able to view the comments on that group add comments to that group.

Are there any API's supporting this

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API doesn't include methods to create groups. Apps can read group information and post to a group's wall, but not create a group. You can read more on the [Facebook Developer pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) about the methods available for groups.